# REST/Ajax code run without error but return no items

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, office-365-developer, sharepoint-rest-api

List already have 5 items. But Sharepoint hosted app with given code run without error but return no items. Strange!

```
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(QueryString.SPHostUrl);
        var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(QueryString.SPAppWebUrl);

        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

        executor.executeAsync({
          url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('Waqarreading')/items/?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
          method: "GET", 
          headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
          success: function(data,status,jqXHR){
              console.log("datalists ==== ", data);
              var rslt = JSON.parse(data.body); 
              console.log("datalists rslt ==== ", rslt);
          }, 
          error: function(jqXHR,status,exception){

          } 
        });
```

Request sent to: `https://waqarmuneer-5237833b21c83e.sharepoint.com/ContentPoint/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('Waqarreading')/items/?@target=%27https://waqarmuneer.sharepoint.com%27`

Comment: Disregard my last comment - I am looking at the exact code you used in the article, let me digest that :)

Comment: Do you use Fiddler? If yes, could you check what response you are getting back, if any, after your request gets submitted?

Comment: Another question for you - if you put alert("success!") in your success delegate function instead of console.log statements, does it alert after the request is sent to server?

Comment: Doesn't a SharePoint REST call return data in `data.d.results`, not `data.body`?

Comment: @DylanCristy I got data.d.results but it returns empty array.

Comment: What's being returned in console?  Have you tried ajax/xhr instead of the RequestExecutor?  As long as you use that url, you don't need to use RequestExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable for url before executer.executeasync and use developer tool to get the url and then paste it on browser see  if it I returning data or not, if not then you have to correct the rest query. Also check data.d.results instead of data.body